# The value of "key" is null

Tags: android, android-intent

I have this problem:

I want to use variables in different activities, but my key value is null.

I have this written on the main activity:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
    intent.putExtra("score",score);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

And I have this written in my second activity:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
score10 = extras.getString("score");
score20 = Integer.parseInt(score10);
score30 = score20;
```

What should I do?

Comment: What is the var type for `score` in `intent.putExtra("score",score);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### MainActivity.Java

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
    if(score != null ){
        intent.putExtra("score", String.valueOf(score));
    }
    else {
        String test = "";
        intent.putExtra("score", test);
    }
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

#### MainActivity2.java

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
score10 = extras.getString("score");
if(score10 != null || score10 != ""){
    score20 = Integer.parseInt(score10);
    score30 = score20;
}
```

That's done.

Comment: it doesnt work, score is int and it has a value of a hundred which can go down to zero.

Comment: check now, i updated the answer. if it works then accept my answer

Comment: What do you mean by "That's done."? Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Like you mentioned `score` is `int`. Try this:

```
Intent extras = getIntent();
int score10 = extras.getIntExtra("score", 0); 
score30=score10;
// Whatever other allocations you need
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 extras.getIntExtra("score",0);
```

Instead of

```
  extras.getString("score");
```

Comment: btw his extras is a `bundle` instance

Comment: That method takes a second parameter of the default value

Comment: but he is using putExtra. putExtra used to store string values

Comment: @Dnyanesh nope, put `extraExtra` is an overloaded method in `Intent` class. Takes a bunch of values

Comment: @Dnyanesh No, check the Intent documentation again